# Apache website permissions under Centos 7

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, centos7

1. I have a site in dir /home/nbo/mysiteA. (nbo is the user)
2. I've create a new dir structure /var/www/mysiteB/public_html
3. public_html is a symlink to /home/nbo/mysiteA
4. **httpd.conf** settings:

   ```
   Listen 82
   <VirtualHost *:82>
     ServerName mysite.com

     DocumentRoot /var/www/mysiteB/public_html/
     DirectoryIndex index.php

     <Directory "/var/www/mysiteB/public_html/">
       Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOnwerMatch
       Require all granted
       AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

   </VirtualHost>
   ```

> When I test the website I get a 403 error (**Forbidden** You don't
>   have permission to access /index.php on this server.)

- I've already tried to add the **nbo** user to **apache group**.
- I've already tried to change the ownership of the entire site to **apache user**.

**What I'm missing?**

Comment: Try changing `Options` line to `Options +All` and restart

Comment: Tried, same thing. In the error.log I get this "AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not accessible".